# DC.js controlsUseVisibility is not a function

Tags: javascript, d3.js, charts, dc.js

I am trying to implement dc.js but getting error as

```
Uncaught TypeError: yearRingChart.width(...).height(...).dimension(...).group(...).innerRadius(...).controlsUseVisibility is not a function
```

can any body help me on this as i am new to dc.js

[here](http://codepen.io/7deepakpatil/pen/vXQvmk?editors=1000) is the code pen please check the console i have loaded all the js on the proper order.

Comment: You're probably using too early a version of dc.js - I think you'll need the 2.0 betas (currently 2.0.0-beta.32) for this feature. It's close to release and quite stable.